# Not able to get String array in onActivtyResult method Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

In my case there are two activities Activity A and B
in Activty A i am calling startActivtyForResult and starting Activty B.
In activty B i am putting String array as extra as below,

```
// set selected contacts on DONE button press
private void setSelctedcontacts() {

    ArrayList<Contact> selectedListWithPhoneNo = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    ArrayList<Contact> selectedListWithEmail = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    ArrayList<String> emailAddressList=new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] ToAdress=new String[100];
    int j=0;
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    ArrayList<Contact> contactList = contactAdapter.originalList;
    for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
        Contact contact = contactList.get(i);
        if (contact.isSelected()) {
            if(contact.getContactNumber()!=null)
                selectedListWithPhoneNo.add(contact);
            if(contact.getContactEmail()!=null)
            {
                ToAdress[j]=contact.getContactEmail();
                emailAddressList.add(contact.getContactEmail());
                selectedListWithEmail.add(contact);
                //Toast.makeText(ContactManager.this, "email:"+contact.getContactEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                //.show();

                j++;
            }               
        }
    }
    if (selectedListWithPhoneNo.size() > 0) {
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("SELECTED_CONTACTS_NUMBER", selectedListWithPhoneNo);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    } else if(selectedListWithEmail.size() > 0){
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("SELECTED_CONTACTS_EMAIL", selectedListWithEmail);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("EMAIL_ADDRESS_LIST", emailAddressList);
        intent.putExtra("TO_ADDRESS", ToAdress);
        //intent.put
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    }else {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
    }
    finish();
    //System.out.println("selected contacts:"+selectedList.size());
    // Tip: Here you can finish this activity and on the Activty result of the calling activity you fetch the Selected contacts

}
```

onActivtyResult code in Activity A is,

```
             if(data.getExtras().containsKey("SELECTED_CONTACTS_NUMBER")){
                 ArrayList<Contact> selectedList =(ArrayList<Contact>) data.getExtras().getSerializable("SELECTED_CONTACTS_NUMBER");


                 Toast.makeText(ScringoFindFriendsSub.this, "email:"+data.getStringArrayListExtra("EMAIL_ADDRESS_LIST"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();  //i am alwasys getting null here

}
```

i am always getting null in data.getStringArrayListExtra("EMAIL_ADDRESS_LIST")..
SELECTED_CONTACTS_NUMBER & SELECTED_CONTACTS_EMAIL is coming in onActivityResult but EMAIL_ADDRESS_LIST is not coming, i mean its null

Comment: if you are getting null pointer then its a good idea to post stack trace as well.

Comment: Is it crashing or your list is `null`?

Comment: it is coming as null..i want the actual value. i checked while ptting extra into intent,the value is there but onActivityResult i dont know why its not passing

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I don't think you want an 'else if' here:

```
} else if(selectedListWithEmail.size() > 0){
```

If a Contact has a phone and an email, you add him to both lists.  But if there's anyone on the phone list, you won't put the email list into the result.